# Python NAT Hole Punching

Tags: python, tcp, udp, nat, hole-punching

I've built a simple peer 2 peer network and now i'm trying to make it work on external network in order to allow the peers to autoconnect based on a well known node. The point is that i'm trying to send a TCP packet through the NAT but i can't do it.

I've tried a lot of sources and techiniques even UPNP but all python libraries I've tried can't see my gateway as UPNP device for port forward (but this is not the question).

In the end I've also tried to go on some pocs such as the following:
https://github.com/dwoz/python-nat-hole-punching

But nothing seems to work, i tried the stun library but without success.

Any suggest? Thank you.